# QML - getting the code of a JS function as a string

Tags: javascript, qt, function, qml, tostring

It seems like it is possible to get the code of a function in JavaScript, and that it is as simple as:

```
function foo() {...}
foo.toString()
```

However, doing that in QML gives me a rather uninspiring `function () { [code] }`

So is there a way to get the `[code]` part as well? I also tried `JSON.stringify()` but it didn't do any good.

Comment: If it's a built-in function, showing the code wouldn't be useful, as it's likely written in c++.

Comment: I get the `[code]` for every function regardless if they are build in, from c++ or custom user JS functions.

Comment: This is in no way an answer to your question, but I wanted to throw a warning here. Function is the fundamental means of abstraction in javascript. I can see how it would be useful for purposes of testing and tooling to be able to inspect the code of functions at runtime, but that would be breaking the abstraction barrier and could lead to tightly coupled code that would be hard to maintain.

Comment: The purpose is to serialize dynamically composed objects which are not created by a js source, to turn them into code. It is possible to do that for the properties, but not for the functions.

Comment: Indeed it is not a js compliant environment. I've never noticed that anyway.

Comment: @skypjack - IIRC this feature is actually not mandatory to be compliant. It just so happened that most of the widely used implementations support it.

Comment: @ddriver [harmony](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.tostring) revision (I guess it was the same for the original one) says that it's implementation dependent but the result of `toString` must be either evaluable by `eval` or such that `eval` is allowed to throw a syntax error. We can try it, probably `function () { [code] }` falls in the second group, thus it's compliant. :-)

Comment: Well, it neither executes as expected, nor is there are any error. Evaluating `function() { [code] }` returns a `function() { [code] }`. WOOT

Comment: @ddriver So I was right, not compliant. It doesn't help, but one could open a ticket to the Qt project, for QML claims to offer a js compliant environment.

Comment: @skypjack - I didn't notice the Qt documentation stating ECMA compliance, I only find a post somewhat suggesting it is, but nothing concrete: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.devel/11478

Comment: @ddriver I guess you are right, it was my expectation and I ever considered it true, but they never claimed it. Quite strange indeed, at least, in my opinion, the documentation should be clear about that, pointing out the differences.

Comment: @ddriver, see [that](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-hostenvironment.html). They say that *the QML runtime implements the ECMAScript Language Specification standard*. So, it looks to be a bug indeed.

Comment: @skypjack - IMO implementing a standard does not imply "in full"

Comment: @ddriver Well, I agree, but it would help knowing if it's a full implementation or not. :-)

Comment: Looks like [QTBUG-46122](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46122).

Comment: @Meefte - P3 priority - it means it might get done in the next 10 to 20 years :D

Comment: @Meefte well, at least you are confirming that I was right!! :-D

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to sum up the discussion that took place in the comments, for this can be a good response for future searches.

As already stated in the comments, it looks to be a noticeable bug of QML.
[Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-hostenvironment.html) they claim that:

> the QML runtime implements the ECMAScript Language Specification standard

Anyway, it actually doesn't.

Thanks to Meetfe, [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/QTBUG-46122) is the link to the open bug regarding the issue.

The same error seems to be [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-functionlist.html), where they suggest to look at the reference for further details:

> For a detailed description, see the ECMA-262 specification.

It is (at least, it looks to me) a claim of full compatibility and once more it makes me think to a bug, rather than a partial implementation of the specification.

So, unfortunately that is the intended way to stringify a function (it makes sense indeed, for it is an Ecmascript compliant environment), but it doesn't work correctly in QML, even though it should as stated in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-functionlist.html#function-objects

```
Function Properties
    toString()
    apply(thisArg, argArray)
    call(thisArg [, arg1 [, arg2, ...]])
    bind((thisArg [, arg1 [, arg2, …]])
```

For JS-Functions, QT doesn't support another option to get the String of a Function. But if you explain why you want it we might be able to find another solution.

Comment: Your example is not even about QML.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I made a new answer

Comment: Ok, I added the important part

Comment: I have already explained why I need it in the comments below the question. The link you quote says nothing about QML not supporting this functionality, which according to the information referenced by skypjack is mandatory for ECMA compliance.

Comment: because you won't find information about everything that does not exist

Comment: please make sure to put additional information about your question in your question

Comment: if it was ECMA `Function.toString()` would return the Function string