# Print code of property binding in QML

Tags: binding, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Is there a way to print the code of the property binding for a certain property in QML?

For example:

```
root.foo =  Qt.binding(function() {return width + "2"})
console.log(<code of root.foo>)
```

Comment: Btw. I think the function itself is stored in the read-only `fooChanged` property. Unfortunately it seems not to be possible to read-out the code in QML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get body of a function in QML. Here you can read nice post about it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33878445/5163799

I think the same would be with a binding.